# How can I gauge my readiness to start learning a third language?

Tags: multiple-languages, proficiency

Deciding whether to start a third language or continue studying L2 can be completely opinion-based. Some people think English is enough but others don't. But there are always people (For example myself) who always dream of being getting fluent in a third language but don't know whether it's the time to start or not.

I've seen [this question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-is-the-impact-of-studying-a-third-language-in-a-second-language) and I know there may be disadvantages and also advantages and you shouldn't quit L2 let your it get passive in your mind while learning L3.

But my question is

- Are there any criteria to ensure me that I am proficient enough in
  English to start another language? (Suppose that English is the most
  important)
- What factors should I consider in my decision when choosing the right
  time to start?

In fact I'm searching for any statistical evidence, standard , etc to help me decide easier for an opinion-based problem

Comment: this question seems primarly opinion based to me, as in looking for advice whenever to improve English or learn another language. In the end, learn what you'd like to learn. If you have the motivation to learn German or French, nobody is going to stop you. And both languages can definitely be useful.

Comment: @DanieleD I'm not asking for any advice or recommendation. As you see I have used `one` or `someone` in the final questions. If I write a summary of myself, that is because I want to give you an example of a real situation. I am asking what level of proficiency is adequate for someone (anyone with any L2) is adequate to start another language? And is there any particular criteria to ensure that you know enough to start another language? of course if I start German or French, I won't quit studying English to let it get passive in my mind

Comment: I think this is effectively a duplicate of [this question](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/436/13).

Comment: Are you asking when how to tell when you're ready to start learning L3 using L2 or L3 using L1?  L3 using L2 is probably answered by the linked question, and L3 using L1 is really up to you.